# How to conditionally include association definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm able to get the behavior I'd like if I create a Foo class, some STI classes that inherit it (Foo1, Foo2, etc.) and then to add different `has_many :bars` associations to each class. For example:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
end

class Foo1 < Foo
  has_many :bars, -> { where(user_id: 1) }
end
```

I want to be able to call `bars` on an object and get a different association behavior depending on the state of the object. This works, but is there a way to do it without setting up STI?

I tried doing everything inside **foo.rb** but I seem to be loading my first `has_many :bars` definition even if I do something like this:

```
has_many :bars ... if some_method_returning_boolean?
has_many :bars ... if some_other_method_returning_boolean?
```

And even if this did work, it seems kind of clunky.

I also considered scopes, but as far as I understand scopes then I'd have to call `foo.bars.something` and `foo.bars.something_else` instead of relying on the state of the object `foo` to give me `foo.bars` differently. Also, it looks like scopes only cover part of a `has_many` definition but can't modify arguments like `:source`, `:foreign_key`, but I may be wrong.

Is there another way?

Comment: Did you try scopes ?

Comment: I just aded a bit about trying scopes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STI is the correct way of doing this. It's generally understood that any particular model class should have well-defined and *consistent* relationships with other records.

If you have relationships that only apply to certain kinds of records that's exactly what STI is for: Create a subclass that defines these relationships.

You see this all the time. An example would be that both "Parent" and "Student" are of base type "Person", but that the students have a `belongs_to: parent` association and the parents have a `has_many: children` relationship.

Of course this presumes parents are unlikely to become students, and students parents, an assumption that may not be correct. Whatever assumptions you make, I hope there's some serious thinking about if these restrictions are relevant or just overly paranoid.

It's generally bad form to switch types on a record even though it can technically be done. You could use this to adjust how a record's relationships are defined if you think this is strictly necessary.

Generally I'd advise you to stick with a consistent relationship structure. Those records which should not be related to anything don't need those methods physically removed, they can be there while not doing anything useful. They come along for free anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will be satisfacted by overwrite your `bars` method in this way ?
This `super` just return usual result from `something_foo.bars`.

```
class Foo
    def bars
      super.where(something: something_value) if your_condition
      super.where(something_else: something_value) if other_condition
    end
end
```